# How to perform increment or decrement using variable in a view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, view

I want to increment or decrement a value using a varaible within a view in angularjs how to do that

```
var i=0;
<div ng-repeat="user in users" >

       <span>{{user.username}}</span>
i=i+1
</div>
```

is it possible how to do that

Comment: You can't just put plain JavaScript code inside your HTML. For what do you want to use this variable?

Comment: You could use `$index` for achieving a similar result, eg. calling a function like  `ng-click="push(user, $index)"`

Comment: In this scenario, why wouldn't you just set `i = users.length`?